# Polymer: Failed to load resources after build

Tags: polymer

I'm new to polymer. I've followed a couple of tutorials to learn the base of the library. However, I always encounter a problem after building the app.
Here is a summary how to reproduce my problem.

```
polymer --version //returns 1.6.0

mkdir poly-app
cd poly-app
polymer init // Select polymer-2-application
polymer serve --open // works fine
polymer build
polymer serve build/default --open // works fine
```

Now, I would like to export my code to my web server. I copy paste the content of /poly-app/build/default and I paste it on my web server. When I try to access it, it get errors such as:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I found that the problem comes from the following lines of code in /poly-app/build/default/index.html:

```
<script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="/src/poly-app-app/poly-app-app.html">
```

In order to fix the problem, I need to remove the first / in the src and href attribute.

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="src/poly-app-app/poly-app-app.html">
```

Apparently I need to do this manually every time I build the app. Is there any other way to fix automatically?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to serve it from a non root path on your website?
In that case you should set the `basePath` property of the build configuration to the respective path and the generated code should populate the `<base>` tag with the needed information so the urls are working.